# Connecting HC-06 and LM35

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-06, lm35

Hello I am trying to send temperature data via bluetooth using the HC-06 module. Since TXD and RXD only allow 3.3V I have divided the circuit into two like the below image.
Is this method correct? or is there a better way to connect both two?

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. You should be dividing the TX *from* the Arduino (5V) down to 3.3V for the RX into bluetooth.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you for your comment. I'm a little confused. Is the below picture correct. So the purple and green wires should be reversed?

Comment: No, the resistors should be on the green wire not the purple.

Comment: Is the lower module a bluetooth master? If I recall it correctly, the HC-06 module have their firmware set to slave only

Comment: "Who" is on the other end? Once HC-06 is paired with a master - Nexus 7, f/ex, or PC's with Bluetooth 2 - it will communicate just fine. Just remember the HC-05/06 are Bluetooth 2 devices and can't talk to BLE devices -- current iPhones and many current PCs.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by chrisl, you cannot use HC-06 as a `master` device. Its firmware restricts it to behave only as a slave. So even if you are able to process the analog data from `LM 35`, you won't be able to send it using `HC-06`. It would be better if you go for `HC-05` module and try the command `AT+ROLE: x` (x = 1 for master/0 for slave) to get the job done.

Coming to the 3v3 voltage constraint, I would suggest you to go for any Zener diode (in reverse biased mode) with `3.3V Reverse breakdown voltage`. You can check the circuit for this [here](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/33v-1n4728a-zener-used-33-v-voltage-regulator-5-v-source-shown--zener-diode-reverse-breakd-q19274856) and order it from [this link](https://www.ebay.com/p/20-X-1N4728A-1n4728-Vishay-ZENER-Diode-3-3v-1w/1018498160). If this is not possible anyhow, then you can also go for `LM1117 3V3`, but I would personally suggest you to go for zener diode. Comment back if you need any help in future.